# jQuery select links that don't have any JS events linked to them for PJAX to work on links only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pjax

I have a basic shopping website built on WordPress and Woocommerce. Naturally, a lot of the buttons and links have Javascript functions preventing the default behavior of going to the link and doing something else instead. Unfortunately, if I set PJAX to select all `$('a')` elements, then the AJAX functions (or javascript such as even dropdown) functions would seize to work properly and PJAX would take over and refresh the page.

For example, if I would click on a Bootstrap dropdown link, it would go to the link rather than open the dropdown.

I want to know if there's a way to select elements (using jQuery) that only go to their links and have no JS events listening to them.

Comment: Without a lot more information about the page there would be no way to know. Even links with valid URL's might already be doing some ajax for all we know

Comment: I just want to know if there is such a selector for elements (even with valid URLs) that do some JS instead of going to its link that I can prevent. If there isn't one, I'll customize the selector in another way or perhaps give the links I want to PJAX a class.

Comment: no there isn't anything like that and putting classes on the ones you want to target is the best (and most common) way to go

Comment: @yaharga It's not difficult to select all `<a>` elements that have **jQuery** event handlers set on them but not JavaScript global event handlers like `onclick`. Which ones do you need to select?

Comment: @Alternatex I need to select all a elements that have jQuery preventing the links from going to the `href`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this demonstration and let me know if it works for your scenario.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="link-with-handler">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="link-with-handler">Link 3</a>
<a href="#">Link 4</a>
<br>
<br>
<button id="test">Which links have no jQuery click event bound?</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    // Assign handler to links with class 'link-with-handler'
    $('.link-with-handler').click(function() { alert('handled'); });

    // Test function
    $('#test').click(function(){
        // Get all links
        var links = $('a');

        // Iterate through links testing each one for the event handler
        $.each(links, function( index, value ) {
            var ev = $._data(value, 'events');
            if (!ev || !ev.click) { 
                alert(value.innerText + ' has no jQuery click handler bound to it.');  
            }
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/goq7a6bn/2/